# Autosave returing Service Unavailable Without any response text on restore

Tags: ajax

In autosave v:7.x-2.2, I am getting this error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /autosave/restore/post-content-node-form/1361446295/VJ5GdML22KqYgVzxuQXndTd3ibj2iz6mfCg4l-RafXo/bartik
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText:
```

I have searched for it, but didn't get any solution yet.
Any idea, how can I resolve it.

I have checked DB and it is storing entry properly.

-- Thanks

Comment: What exactly have you changed since http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/121755/16495 ? Also, error 500 really means "see server's error.log" - so what's there? or maybe, by a chance, something got logged into watchdog?

Comment: Have you checked your apache/php error logs and your browser's console.log?

Comment: In the browser console log : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Service unavailable (with message))

Comment: OK, but what's in the log on **server side**?

Comment: There is nothing showing in server log related with autosave.

Comment: I got one answer. When I'm disabling sub path auto module the Autosave module is working. I'm able to restore the edited contents. But I don't know why it's happening.